# Should this give an error, and if yes, how to check it? (OpenCL)

Tags: c++, opencl

I am learning to make robust code in OpenCL and facing the following kernel code:

```
string kernel_code =
" void kernel simple_add(global const int *A,    "
"                        global const int *B,    "
"                        global int *C, int n) { "
"                                                "
"   int index = get_global_id(0);                "
"   C[index]=A[index]+B[index];                  "
" }                                              ";
```

And using on purpose the following code for sending it to GPU:

```
Kernel ker(program, "simple_add");
ker.setArg(0, buffer_A);
ker.setArg(1, buffer_B);
ker.setArg(2, buffer_C);
ker.setArg(3, N);
q.enqueueNDRangeKernel(ker,NullRange,NDRange(32),NDRange(32));
q.finish();
```

The thing is, I am using more work items than is needed, so I think I should check if the index is out of bounds on the kernel code. But I am not using it and checking errors returned by enqueueNDRangeKernel or by finish is giving me CL_SUCCESS.. So, or this should not give me errors for some reason or I do not know how to get them.. What is the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in C and C++, going out of bounds in an array is *undefined behaviour* in OpenCL, so it won't necessarily raise an error condition, but can cause pretty much any kind of strange behaviour. So don't rely on your runtime to catch this sort of programming mistake. It's more likely that your program will crash, or even your whole system will crash (if it doesn't use an IOMMU) as a result of this sort of error, rather than an error code in the return value.

As an implementation detail, you will most likely find that buffers are mapped to the GPU's memory space in 4096-byte increments - one page of memory. So if your out-of-bounds access is still within a valid 4096-byte page, it'll more likely behave like a typical CPU-based buffer overflow.

Comment: Unless OpenCL implementation is buggy, I highly doubt it'll crash the system. More plausible is crash of the application, maybe even GPU hang, but definitely not system crash. Otherwise one can easily do an OpenCL-based DoS attack.

Comment: You'd be surprised. On modern GPUs with virtual memory implementations and systems with IOMMUs it's generally not a problem. Earlier GPU generations (e.g. GeForce 8xxx/9xxx) seemed to just use physical memory addresses though, so in the absence of an IOMMU they do indeed cause all kinds of crashes.